# PHP Mailer Could not load language file and Email Body Empty

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Hi I am working with PHP mailer , Without doing any code changes when i send an email  Now , the Email Body is empty . I debug the code and found in the mailer object that

```
[ErrorInfo] => Could not load language file
```

Then I checked the `class.phpmailer.php` `function SetLanguage` from that file the path is

```
mailer/language/phpmailer.lang-en.php
```

in My project the language file is in

```
/var/www/html/my_project/include/mailer/language/phpmailer.lang-en.php
```

So I don't know why PHP mailer cannot identify the file . Do i need the absolute path .

I haven't done any changes recently and suddenly this error appeared and now the Email Body is empty . The email is going but nothing in the body . Can this be a mail server problem ? I am not sure what to do because i haven't done any changes.

Comment: `$mail = new PHPMailer();`
`$mail->SetLanguage("en", 'includes/phpMailer/language/');`

Comment: in my function SetLanguage i have defined the path as the 2 nd parameter  function SetLanguage($lang_type, $lang_path = 'mailer/language/') { , is there any other things that cause this problem , may be email server issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by manually include the path to laguage folder

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetLanguage("en", 'includes/phpMailer/language/');
```

Comment: in my function SetLanguage i have defined the path as the 2 nd parameter  function SetLanguage($lang_type, $lang_path = 'mailer/language/') { , is there any other things that cause this problem , may be email server issue ?

Comment: This call will do nothing because there is no English translation file.

Answer (score 0):

This error has not been set for years. You must be using a very old version of PHPMailer - [get the latest from github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: Hi My code worked perfectly for 2 years , but why suddenly it is giving errors ? can it be a mail server issue .

Comment: This error message used to appear when either the language was set incorrectly, or PHPMailer was asked to display an error for which it did not have a translation. The problem was fixed several years ago. I don't know why you are seeing it now - perhaps something else has changed - for example are you running into issues with gmail authentication, which has changed radically recently? Whatever it is, you should update PHPMailer before doing anything else as many, many bugs have been fixed since then.